# When do two matrices have the same null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices and let $\text{Null Space}(A)=\text{null space}(B)$. What can we say about the two matrices? Are they related in a simple way?

Comment: The answer is no. For example two unrelated invertible matrices share the null space (which is $0$), and nothing else. By the rank-nullity theorem having the same null space implies having the same rank.

Comment: What if the null space is not 0 (say it's one dimensional)?

Comment: Take a basis of the null space and extend it to a basis of $\Bbb R^n$. The other vectors can be mapped to anything by the matrix $A$ and to anything else by the matrix $B$.

Answer (score 3):

The (right) kernel of a matrix can be understood as the orthogonal complement of the rows of the matrix. This immediately implies that $\ker A \subset \ker B$ exactly if the orthogonal complement of the rows of $A$ is a subset of the same for $B$. This is of course the case exactly if the rows of $B$ are part of the subspace spanned by the rows of $A$.

Thus you get the equivalent characterisation $\ker A\subset \ker B$ if and only if the rows of $B$ are spanned by the rows of $A$. Thus also $\ker A = \ker B$ if and only if the rows of $A$ and $B$ span the same subspace.

Comment: Or in other words $A$ and $B$ have the same reduced row echelon form.